Does deriving copy for large structs have any effect on performance?
In Rust, Copy types are bitwise copyable. For a type which is "large", this might be quite an expensive operation.
For example, consider a struct containing many integers. Enough for it to be considered "large" such that a bitwise copy operation is "expensive".

I use "large" and "expensive" in double quotes to avoid specifying what this might be in comparison to. Is it a struct with 10 i64s "large"? What about 100?

struct LargeThing {
    some_data: [i64; 100],
}

What, if any, performance considerations are there for deriving Copy as well as Clone?
The book Programming Rust 2nd Edition gives seemingly confusing information.
It states that, for a Copy type aka POD type aka non-RAII type, both Copy and Clone implementations are (identical) bit copy operations.

POD = plain old data. RAII = resource aquisition is initialization - here it just means there is some non-trivial resource to manage, like a block of memory, etc.
A Copy type/POD type/non-RAII type is a type which is composed entirely of other Copy types.

This information seems to suggest that Copy and Clone for a Copy type should have identical performance. (Machine code.)
However, the Rust compiler may also do some optimizations.
For example, in the following code
let x = LargeThing::new();
let y = x;
let z = y;

I would suggest the compiler at some stage should be able to optimize this to
let z = LargeThing::new();

But - how does this interact with the borrow checker and language semantic rules more broadly?
If a type does not implement Copy then x = y becomes a move. This is a bitwise copy operation accompanied by the borrow checker recognizing that y is now invalidated.
On the other hand, if a type does implement Copy the semantics of the operator = is changed. It now means a bitwise copy (same as before) however y is not invalidated.
Combining this with any optimizations which might occur, in the example above, it is relatively obvious that both x and y are invalidated if LargeThing is "moved" rather than "copied".
Whereas, if LargeThing is a Copy type, and has #[derive(Copy, Clone)], it is no longer the case that the variables x and y are invalidated by the operation =.
Have I fully understood the language semantics? The book Programming Rust describes some reasons why you might not want to implement Copy, but it doesn't say anything about this in the context of runtime performance. Does that mean there is no difference?

You have indeed understood correctly, and there is no runtime difference between a move and a copy. Indeed, the documentation for the Copy trait literally answers your question: "It’s important to note that in these two examples, the only difference is whether you are allowed to access x after the assignment. Under the hood, both a copy and a move can result in bits being copied in memory, although this is sometimes optimized away.".

Tangentially related: "Claiming, auto and otherwise" by Niko Matsakis.

@eggyal To summarize the consequence of this - Clone really is just a way to syntactically indicate that = might be performing an expensive operation? In a sense, it is almost like syntactic sugar. The call to clone in y = x.clone() is just there to mark that operator = is probably performing some expensive operation, like allocating memory, creating a new file handle, etc...

Unlike Copy (that determines whether the source is invalidated), Clone is (almost) entirely a regular trait with no special meaning.   Indeed, its documentation explains: "A common trait for the ability to explicitly duplicate an object.  Differs from Copy in that Copy is implicit and an inexpensive bit-wise copy, while Clone is always explicit and may or may not be expensive. In order to enforce these characteristics, Rust does not allow you to reimplement Copy, but you may reimplement Clone and run arbitrary code."

In other words: yes I broadly agree with what you said in your previous comment: but if I was being truly pedantic I'd argue Clone isn't syntactic sugar nor can an explicit call to .clone() be considered "probably expensive" as it might very well just be implemented as a memcopy.  Whilst it's not required that Clone::clone for T: Copy be a memcopy (and therefore it cannot be relied upon for safety), it is nevertheless often expected.  Indeed, some specialisations in the standard library assume as much.  See also discussion in https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3197

@eggyal That makes sense, thanks

TL;DR: Currently this has no effect, but it may have in the future.

If I understand correctly, you are concerned that implementing Copy will mean that since you are allowed to use your moved data, the compiler cannot get rid of the move anymore.
This is a good thinking and a good concern. However, for such optimization to be valid, we need to ask ourselves whether really you are disallowed to use a moved-from value.
It may be obvious that yes, since the borrow checker forbids that. But the reality is... it's complicated. It's complicated because we have unsafe code. So, this becomes an operational semantics question: are moves and copy the same in the Abstract Machine, or different like in the surface language?
And the answer, like most Rust semantic answers, is "it's undecided (yet)". Which means the worst of both worlds: an unsafe code author cannot rely on this to be allowed, but the compiler is not allowed to rely on this being disallowed and optimize accordingly.
So, currently the compiler does not elide moves based on Copy. It may or may not in the future (it is not clear to me whether LLVM has the ability to signify that, but that can always be fixed).
However, there is another area where Copy can improve performance. The standard library are allowed to turn clones of Copy-implementing types into copies, since a Clone implementation for such type that is not a bitwise copy is a violation of the Clone contract (I am not sure whether the compiler is also allowed to rely on this, but I believe it was decided that no). The standard library does this, for example, in specializations of collections: cloning an array or a Vec of Copy types is implemented as a memcpy() to copy the elements, which may optimize better than calls to Clone if LLVM does not understand it can be a bitwise copy.
